# Using output stream overloading operator for pointers

Tags: c++, instance, overloading

I have a coursework to submit and I almost finished it all. But I'm stuck in
a bit where I have to read a class instance to a file using output stream operator. the output stream operator takes instance as an argument but I need
to use it for a pointer to an instance. any help please?

My output stream operator implementation is:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, sequence &s)
{
    out<<s.number_of_samples;//<<s.samples;
    s.samples=new float [s.number_of_samples];
    for(int i=0; i<s.number_of_samples; i++) out<<s.samples[i];
    return(out);
}
```

The bit where it reads the instance to a file is:

```
ofstream output_filtered_samples_file("output.txt");
sequence* filtered_sequence = test_FIR.apply_filter(test_sequence);
output_filtered_samples_file<<filtered_sequence;
```

Full code is http://ideone.com/V0Xavo

Comment: More people might comment if you tagged your question with the language.  I'm guessing C or C++.

Comment: I did that, thank you

Comment: "I need to use it for a pointer" Please explain why you think so.

Comment: because the function APPLY_FILTER return a pointer to an instance, and I need to read this instance to a file

Answer (score 0):

Dereference the pointer . . .

```
output_filtered_samples_file<<*filtered_sequence;
```

Comment: use a const ref in your << overload and then what is the error?

Comment: Run in debug. At what line does it bail and what is the message?

Comment: I can't press on the debug button, when I run the code the black window (don't know what's called) appear then it crashes

Comment: post your code on ideone and add it to your question. At least we'll then see a runtime error

Comment: ideone knows of no filesystem, so pump in some dummy data to make it crash

Comment: sorry how to do that, I'm a student taking "Software engineering basics"

Comment: Edit your question to include your ideone link and maybe someone will help

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Write an `operator<<()` that accepts a pointer
2. Pass the dereferenced value.

The second option is probably best:

```
output_filtered_samples_file << *filtered_sequence;
```

Your `operator<<()` should prefer to accept a reference to const, as nobody expects it to modify the object:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const sequence &s)
```

This will help you identify what's wrong with the body of the method.